# How to put an existing image value to $_FILES array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a form and there are some text fields and image fields. Users can edit this form. I can fetch existing images to form and they can see the image in the form but when they submit it without doing anything I can not see images in the $_FILES array.

How can I put this images to $_FILES array.

```
<div class="md-card-content">
    <h3 class="heading_a uk-margin-small-bottom">
        Upload Image
    </h3>
    <input 
         type="file" 
         id="input-file-b" 
         name='gallery_image[<?php echo $counter; ?>]' 
         data-default-file="<?php echo $image['image_path']; ?>" 
         class="dropify">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

File does not support value attribute so its not possible.

You can add a condition to see if the $_FILES is valid array and has data
or not before doing anything.

```
If (is_array($_FILES) and count($_FILES) > 0) {
    //save the new file and delete old file
} else {
   //Need not to do anything as the file is already saved in your system
}
```